# Submit Callback parameters in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, callback

I'm generating some divs and radio buttons with diferents ids depending of a "for" indentifier, like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Opc.Count; i++)
{
    <input id="maininfo_@(i)" type="radio" name="maininfo" value="@(value)" checked="@maininfo.Selected" />
    <div id="info-@(i)" />
}
```

I have too an ajax call like this

```
$("input[name='maininfo']").change(function () {
    var value = $("input[name='maininfo']:checked").val();
    $.post("/Opc/Info?value=" + value, submitCallback);
});
```

and this is the callback function:

```
var submitCallback = function (data) {
    $("#info").html(data.Result.Html);
}
```

The idea is show all radiobuttons and, when one is checked, show the information just below of each radiobutton. For this reason, I need a callback parameter ("for" identifier) to show the correct info. But I don't know how to do this correctly and eficiently.

Comment: Under what event is the `$.post` being called

Comment: I editted the comment before. I'm so sorry for no complete info. Now, I have put the context of post call